# Same Serial number on every page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using client side pagination using bootstrap in the table.I wanted to add serial number in every page such that on page 1 S.No starts from 1 to 50 then on page 2 s.No should be 51 to 100....and so on

I have changed my css

```
.table {
 counter-reset: serial-number;  /* Set the serial number counter to 0     */
}

.table td:first-child:before {
 counter-increment: serial-number;  /* Increment the serial number   counter */
  content: counter(serial-number);  /* Display the counter */
 }
```

But now the problem is on page 2 the S.No starts again from 1 to 50 and So on page 3..Can somebody help me to achieve the correct Serial number series on other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seed the counter manually, in the `counter-reset` property:

```
counter-reset: serial-number 50; /* Set counter to 50 */
```

Of course you'd have to manually calculate this initial value. In a javascript pagination callback, you could update this with something like:

```
document.querySelector('.table').style.counterReset = 'serial-number ' + (zeroIndexedPageNo * pageSize);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3b7z037f/)

Comment: it resets and starts count from 51 every page including page 1

Comment: Yes, `reset-counter: ... 50` sets it to 50. You need to set it to what you want it to be.

Comment: I think u didin't got my question... i want page 1 S.no should be ! to 50 and page 2 51 to 100 and on page 3 101 to 150

Comment: Yes, then on page 1, reset the counter to 0, on page 2, reset it to 50, etc. See my updated answer for an example of how you can update the property, but it's really like you update any property.